# How to scroll left/right using karate appium?

Tags: appium, karate, appium-android

I'm not able to scroll with Karate appium. My native app only shows half of the grid, i need to scroll all the way to the right, and click the button. I have tried all the friendly locators, mouse operations, special keys. Not moving at all.

mouse().move(x, y).down().move(x, y).up()
What else i can use? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Friendly locator and Mouse API are supported only on the web so far, for native mobile. I would try `script`

```
   And driver.optional('@Views').click()
  And driver.script("mobile: scroll", { "strategy" : "accessibility id", "selector": "Seek Bar"})
  And driver.optional('@Seek Bar').click()
  And def seekbarId = driver.elementId("#io.appium.android.apis:id/seek")
  And driver.script("mobile: swipeGesture", { "elementId" : seekbarId, "direction": "left", "height": 50, "width" : 1080, "percent": 0.8 })
  And driver.delay(2000)
  And driver.script("mobile: swipeGesture", { "elementId" : seekbarId, "direction": "right", "height": 50, "width" : 1080, "percent": 0.8 })
  And driver.delay(2000)
  And driver.script("mobile: swipeGesture", { "elementId" : seekbarId, "direction": "left", "height": 50, "width" : 1080, "percent": 0.8 })
```

[image]

take a look at this android doc https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-mobile-gestures.md#mobile-swipegesture

Comment: Can you please provide working code snippet as provided in #1686 issue? It would help me a lot. Also app elements are having the locator as class and text only

Comment: @GauravSaini check the updated answer